# 3D support from Nouveau drivers

Tags: 11.04, nvidia, nouveau

My GPU is an old one (FX 5500), but it supports 3D acceleration with the NVIDIA driver. There is experimental acceleration support in the open source drivers as far as I know, and I would like to try it out on Natty. What are my options?

I know about [X Updates PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-x-swat/+archive/x-updates) by the [Ubuntu-X team](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-x-swat), and it worked with the binary blob for me. Can it provide open-source 3D acceleration?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's easy, just install `libgl1-mesa-dri-experimental` package which provides experimental 3d support for nouveau driver.

Comment: Official repo or PPA?

Comment: Offical repositories.

Comment: Does it work? :|

Comment: @RobinJ, I had upgraded to Oneiric. Will reinstall Natty and inform you. Though if it doesn't work for me, it'd be probably because of my really old hardware - just so you know.

Comment: @RobinJ, installed on a persistent live USB. Works.

Comment: Ok, I should remember to take a look at that when 11.10 comes out. I only hope they've taken my graphic card from the blacklist :s

Comment: @RobinJ, my GPU is also blacklisted, but looks like the experimental support ignored it. And please tag me like I did with @[username], or I wouldn't know you replied.